# JUnit - Synchronized method

Tags: java, junit

```java
public static synchronized int excuteBatch(string pathfile) {
    ProcessBuilder pro = new ProcessBuilder();
    Process prs = null;
    try {
        pro.command(pathfile);
        prs = pro.start();
        prs.waitFor();
        int rs = prs.exitValue();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // ...
}
```

I guess I need to use multithreading for this, but I've got no idea even how to start my @Test. Please, advise!

Comment: your method is private , You must write test case for the Public method invoking this method, If u can share ur public method ?

Comment: You don't write unit tests to verify that a method carries this or that keyword. You write unit tests to ensure that the public contract of your public methods hold. Whether you need to create multiple threads in your test scenarios... Nobody can say that without looking at the overall design of your class(es). Unless you provide more details, nothing else can be said here.